# How can I store an Object in an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm learning to code. I have started a little project where I design a text-based RPG.
I am struggling with storing and retrieving objects in and from an array.
Please have a look at my progress so far and tell me what I am doing wrong.
If I am using a wrong approach please also let me know how to do the whole thing smarter :)

First I define some properties of the player:

```
static class Globals
{
    public static string playername;
    ...
    public static object[] playerInventory = new object[4];
}
```

Then I create the weapon class:

```
public class Weapon
{
    public string weaponName;
    public int weaponBaseDamage;
    

    public Weapon(string name, int baseDamage)
    {
        weaponName = name;
        weaponBaseDamage = baseDamage;
    }
```

Then I create the first basic weapon and try to store it in an array.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Weapon StartSword = new Weapon("My first Sword", 1);
        Globals.playerInventory[0] = StartSword;
        Console.WriteLine(StartSword.weaponName); // This works
        Console.WriteLine(Globals.playerInventory[0]); // This prints "CSharp_Shell.Weapon", but I expected "StartSword"
        Console.WriteLine(Globals.playerInventory[0].weaponName); // This results in an Error
```

The unexpected result of the second WriteLine command tells me that something must be quite wrong, but I don't know what it is and how to fix it. Any advice is welcome! (And please keep in mind that I am new to Coding).

Comment: Are all the inventory items weapons?

Comment: Object has no property/field called “weaponName” so it is not type-valid. Use a generic collection (with an interface if required) and/or the as/is operators. The first WriteLine works because it accepts an Object-typed expression, and all objects have a ToString() method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/collections

Comment: When you print an object, it will print out the type of the object, in your case, the class which is `Weapon` plus a prefix. Referring to `Console.WriteLine(Globals.playerInventory[0]);`

Comment: You must cast your Globals.playerInventory[0] before to access its property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's required Typecasting. Please try like below:

```
Console.WriteLine(((Weapon)Globals.playerInventory[0]).weaponName)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, lets look at what your code does:

```
Weapon StartSword = new Weapon("My first Sword", 1);
Globals.playerInventory[0] = StartSword;
Console.WriteLine(StartSword.weaponName); // This works
```

Above you create an object of the type Weapon with the name "My first Sword". And then print the name of that public property that is populated in the constructor.

```
  Console.WriteLine(Globals.playerInventory[0]); // This prints "CSharp_Shell.Weapon", but I expected "StartSword"
```

Here you try to write an object. But an object is not a string so c# will automatically try to convert that to a string and will look at the type. So it is expected that it will not write the properties but a representation of the type.

```
Console.WriteLine(Globals.playerInventory[0].weaponName); // This results in an Error
```

Globals.playerInventory is defined as `object[] playerInventory`, so even if we know that you have entered an object of type weapon there, we need to specify that. Either by letting playerInventory be of the type `Weapon[] playerInventory`, or by type casting your object before using its properties, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(((Weapon)Globals.playerInventory[0]).weaponName);
```